XML file is not being copied to output directory in .NET 8
I am working on a .NET 8 C# application that contains a XML file nested within multiple folders. I have set the properties of the XML file to have RootContent and "Copy Always" for the build action/copy to output directory setting, and the XML file is NOT being copied to the Debug\net8.0-windows folder as expected.
If I set the "Build Action" to "None", I get the nested folder structure in the debug, however, I need just the xml file in the main root output folder. My DLLs are copied correctly to the output folder so the output folder is there and created correctly - just for some reason this XML file is not copied to the output bin based on the properties set.
Note: my application was previously setup to run on .NET 4.8 where all of these settings worked correctly and copied the XML file to the output folder as expected.
I tried updating the .csproj manually, however, we could not get the XML file to output to the root directory by itself, i.e. not within the nested folders. RootContent I believe was supposed to handle this.

What version of Visual Studio are you using, and is it on Mac or PC?

Hi @user27425749, Check the Debug\net8.0-windows (or appropriate configuration) folder to confirm that the file is in the root of the output directory. If the file is still not copying, clear the bin and obj folders and rebuild the project to ensure there are no cached build artifacts causing the issue.

Hello, i'm using visual studio 2022. I have checked the output path and it just has bin\ and obj\ which appear to be the default. The xml file will be placed within the output, however, it is placed within the folders that it is within. The goal is that just the single xml file is placed in the root of the output folder. I thought root content would do this, and has in the past on other versions, however, it is not working here.
